# Transfer iTunes playlist to iPhone

Tags: itunes, data-transfer, playlist

Could anyone tell me how to transfer a playlist from iTunes (12.5.3) to my iPhone? 
I've tried selecting manually manage music, but the playlist does not appear in selection at all.

I've also tried Wondershare TunesGo, but I have the same issue, no single playlist appears for me to select.

I appreciate any tips you might have.

Answer (score 1):

Using iTunes 12 you can select the playlists to copy with the following steps:

- Connect your device to the computer.
- Select the icon for your device, located at the upper-left.
- Select the “Music” option on the left pane.
- Ensure the “Sync Music” check-box is selected.
- In the “Playlists” section, check the playlists you wish to sync with your iOS device.
- Select “Sync” and your playlist should sync.

[image]

---

In the case your problem is related to the fact the you are not able to see any playlist [this answer](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6615074?tstart=0) may provide a solution for you.